# Why are artificial languages created always by individuals and not by international institutions?

Tags: constructed-language, esperanto, lojban

Do linguists and scientist have some international coordinated program/authority where the goal is to create the artificial language for all peoples on this planet?

As far as I know, this was always done by individuals instead of organisations.

E.g.:

```
Esperanto - L. L. Zamenhof (1887)
Loglan - James Cooke Brown (1955)
Slovio - Mark Hučko (1999)
```

and even Lojban and others were created by small groups of people.

Why big organisations such as UN or I don't know European Parliament or big linguistic institutions and schools are not involved?

Why is creating a common language such a big problem?

There are so many linguists and if they work together in teams across the whole planet, I think that in 10 years or less we have the best auxiliary language.

Or am I wrong and are there such international collaborations in progress?

Comment: Questions can have a maximum of 5 tags, if more tags are needed you need to remove some of them.

Comment: I don't think the motivations behind individual vs. group creation of artificial languages is a linguistics question at all. It's also 100% subjective since we can't get official responses for artificial language institutions telling us why they don't exist.

Comment: @hippietrail Graduates of undergraduate and graduate programs in Linguistics apply their training in many diverse areas, including language pedagogy, speech pathology, speech synthesis, natural language interfaces, search engines, machine translation, forensics, naming, and of course all forms of writing, editing, and publishing. **Perhaps the most widely appreciated application was contributed by UCSC Linguistics alumnus Marc Okrand, who invented the Klingon language for Star Trek.**

Comment: Ido was not developed by Delegation for the Adoption of an International Auxiliary Language. That organisation existed solely to select an international auxiliary language, and it selected one created 9based on Esperanto) by a Frenchman called Couturat. The language was neither created nor developed by that "Delegation".

Comment: The only neutral international language recognised at an international language is Esperanto. The World Esperanto Association now enjoys consultative relations with the United Nations and is using its position to speak out in favour of the need to protect endangered languages. See - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eR7vD9kChBA&feature=related The new online course www.lernu.net has 125 000 hits per day and Esperanto Wikipedia enjoys 400 000 hits per day. That can't be bad :)

Comment: I have no problems with Marc Okrand or with questions about Klingon linguistics but this question is just soliciting speculation which Stack Exchange says it's not about. That's what forums are for.

Comment: Voting to close, not because I don't like auxlangs, but because an auxlang question shouldn't be "Auxlangs are dumb, am I right or am I right?" Then marking the presumed answer. Better to ask a question that is more narrow, targeted and objective. (and there is something about good/bad subjective, I barely understand that-- but objective question seem to be almost always good)

Comment: @MatthewMartin Just to be sure: where do you see that kind of question? I didn't see it in the question body (I would have edited that out in that case). Thanks. :)

Comment: The "why is this such a big problem" and picking the "well this is such a bad idea that orgs should distance themselves from it" answer. In any case, it still isn't an objectively answerable question, except to mention that organizations have tried (and national government do impose lingua francas, normally natural language ones).

Comment: `Couturat` was the head of the "Delegation..." and acted, most likely, together with `Louis de Beaufront`, who was behind the changes that made Ido out of Esperanto. The language was adopted and recommended by the delegation, however...

Comment: I think Interlingua is created by an institution.

Comment: This question invites very subjective answers and should be closed.  That said, it also based on a false assumption to which there are many counterexamples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possible answers is that conlangs are arts, and to make art, you have to be creative. Being creative, in turn, implies living in comfort, and it has always been easier to create individual comfort than to make some comfort for an institution, or for a society.

Answer (score 12):

First of all, this goal is seen as somewhat utopic today.

If it was ok about 100-130 years ago for Johann Martin Schleyer (the inventor of Volapük, the first constructed language that become relatively widespread), and possibly for Zamenhof (inventor of Esperanto) too*  nowadays the goal of introduction a neutral, constructed language for international communication seems to be absolutely unrealistic. Every language is backed by the economy of the state it comes from and there is no any neutral organisation (like UNO, for example) which would have a distantly similar influence to economy of English, Chinese or Spanish speaking countries.

**- even though there are some allegations that Esperanto was just a part of his philosophy, hillelism (later changed to [homaranism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homaranismo)), and potentially aimed only at Jews.*

By the way, the original goal "to become a second language for all people in the world", that [Esperanto movement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperanto_movement) (not the language!) claimed during its early development (so-called "[Fina venko](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finvenkismo)", the *final victory*) has been superseded by another concept, described in the "Manifest of Raumo" and therefore called [raumism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raumism). It "emphasizes instead the fact that the Esperanto-speaking community has itself become a culture, worthy of preservation and promotion for its own sake." (Wikipedia).

Second, the language were not "created" by individuals, in Esperanto they prefer to use the word "proposed", or "initially proposed". The original project of Esperanto language, as proposed by Zamenhof, was (slightly) reformed during the first years to adapt it to real usage (most dramatic change was the changes to correlatives). This is true for other language projects as well, they often evolved dramatically over time and the language was re-tailored once some practical gaps became evident.

And, thirdly, there are also languages which were from the very beginning created by many (at least >2) people, for example:

- [Interlingua](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlingua) -- created by [International Auxiliary Language
  Association](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Auxiliary_Language_Association).
- [Ido](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ido_%28language%29) -- was developed by [Delegation for the
  Adoption of an International Auxiliary Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_for_the_Adoption_of_an_International_Auxiliary_Language).

Both languages were created not only by group of people, they were created by professional linguists (in contrast to oculist Zamenhof, pastor Schleyer, naval officier de Wahl (occidental/interlingue) etc.). But this didn't help much for them to become popular and widely used.

Answer (score 9):

Why would an organization **want** to create a language? For what purpose would it be used? Who would pay for it?

If you're thinking of a language that would suit as a lingua franca, we already have one, it's called English. **Best** is not the issue here, a language needn't be "good" in order to be popular.

Just making a language, by committee or not, won't make it be used as a means of communication. It must have something extra, like a community of some sorts, which for instance Esperanto has.

Having some organization decree that some specific language is to be used instead of some other language rarely ends well. It has been used as an important and integral part of indoctrination and wholesale destruction of local and indigenous culture for centuries. Did you know there once were "schools for the primitives", in at least the US (american indians), Australia (aborigines) and even my own country Norway (sami). Kids were taken from their parents and punished harshly for using their mother tongues and/or keeping to their parents beliefs and customs. Another tried and tested technique is a little more direct: genocide. Both methods have proven to work splendidly when the goal is to replace one language with another.

What organization in its right mind would risk that blemish on its reputation today?

Besides, the purpose of linguistics is not to create language but to study it. While there are linguist that dabble in language construction, it is generally not to create the final and best language to replace all other languages, just as botanist aren't in the business of making the one, true plant to supercede all other plants. Linguists do not weight features up against each other and attempt to prove that, say, three tenses is better than five. Linguists describe, they do not prescribe.

Comment: **"Kids were taken from their parents and punished harshly for using their mother tongues and/or keeping to their parents beliefs and customs."** Yes,I'm aware of such phenomena, my grand-grand father was punished with a stick called ["trstenica"](http://img.blesk.cz/img/1/full/510413-img-telesne-tresty-skola-vychova-rakoska-nasili-sikana-zak-ucitel.jpg) in a Slovak school because he doesn't know how to pray in Hungarian. Slovakia was part of Kingdom of Hungary. **"Why would an organization want to create a language?"** To make this planet a better place. What's wrong with 1 common 2nd lang?

Comment: Perfect spot for a Hitchhikers-quote: _"the poor [Babel fish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_fish_%28The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy%29#Babel_fish), by effectively removing all barriers to communication between different cultures and races, has caused more and bloodier wars than anything else in the history of creation."_ It does not follow that one common 2nd lang will make the world a better place.

Comment: ;D I have taken a look at lojban and they have droped out "w" and "q" (W is already v, and q is k or k+j/i+u) and the language looks very interesting. And I think that somebody will create a language in the future that will be more universal (I know there is mathematics already) and easier to learn than English. You may see it differently as a native speaker but English is very hard to learn and not very logical to be honest. Many things are missing (easy gender distinguish; friend is he or she?) and many things are not necessary at all (dozens of tenses instead of 3 and maybe some continous).

Comment: **"If you're thinking of a language that would suit as a lingua franca, we already have one, it's called English."** Sorry, but Esperanto or Spanish or Slavio is much more easier to learn and less illogical and mch consistent. English is the most schizophrenic language I have ever seen. It has the biggest vocabulary in the World, but the worst grammar and spelling rules. Just consider the difference between written and read e.g. to/too/two it's a phonetic-analyze nightmare and not suitable for digital processing at all. Esperanto and esp. lojban is designed to be very logical and unambiguous.

Comment: English is not my native language, I officially started learning it in school when I was ten. It is the best of my non-mother tongues though.

Comment: A lingua franca doesn't need to be easy to learn, logical or consistent. It just needs to already be popular. Network effect FTW.

Comment: ok, just to let you know that I am not saying that English is ugly. I think that it sounds very good in songs and it's popular in music because it sounds good. I am just saying that it's not the easiest and most universal language, in my opinion.

Comment: **"A lingua franca doesn't need to be easy to learn, logical or consistent. It just needs to already be popular. A lingua franca doesn't need to be easy to learn, logical or consistent. It just needs to already be popular."** yes, you are right. I mean, it's just weird that there are only a few artificial languages and except Esperanto and Klingon ;) nobody gives a F ;)

Comment: The mere fact that this conversation is happening in English...

Comment: English has two tenses: past and non-past. It has a lot of periphrastic constructions, many of which may have temporal meanings (but often other meanings such as aspect, potentiality).

Answer (score 3):

One powerful husband and wife couple had created an organization before Interlingua was formalized. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_Vanderbilt_Morris

Comment: Various Political Parties (i.a.Italian Radical Party, Irish Green Party) and Religious Organizations (Brazilian Spiritism and Legion of Good Will) have notable support for Esperanto.

Comment: Note that you can always edit your own answers by including essential details straight there. No need to have them as comments.

Answer (score 2):

Please read the [UNESCO minute](http://www.lingvo.org/un)s in 1954,which recommended (recognised) the use of Esperanto. It is because the leaders of many countries are selfish to control the people for letting the people the literacy, thus they don't make Esperanto as a subject in the school. However, Esperanto was researched [in 1921](http://mesg2012.blogspot.com/2012/12/french-business-would-use-esperanto-but.html) and to be the best language in business. All people know the French government halted this project as they thought French is going to stay forever but they are wrong and now the English is another ['dying language'][3]. However, Indonesia government, the Ministry of Foreign Affairs has decided to make Esperanto a subject for the young diplomats.

Brazil made Esperanto as an elective subject in 2009.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about *mental design*.

Looking at Esperanto, and its initial creator, the *non-linguist* Zamenhof. He actually took years playing with notions (not entirely alone), and there are many ideas in the language, that are worth essaying on. For instance endings -a (adj), -e (adv), -o (n) and suffixes -in- -ist- -ebl- have the feature starting with a vowel, so they are chainable.

Unknown to many, even Esperanto speakers, Zamenhof first played with a proto-version, trying out other vowels for endings. Though the pronunciation of "..io" more involves a stop than a y transition, he refrained from "..ijo..".

Zamenhof also chose very short consonant cut-off monosylabic digits (except for 1): unu du tri *kvar* _kvin_ ses *sep* _ok_ naŭ *dek*. This helps with counting (aloud), an area where a foreign speaker often reverts to his native language.

So a commitee not necessarily is better suited for such initial design work. The large manco of Esperanto is its undocumentedness. And - beside the more passive Akademio de Esperanto - one would have hoped for more productive linguistic commitees.

Consider Interlingua, which is linguistically based, and community oriented. The language has other merits, but I find its concept certainly not better funded. I would rather delve into Lingua Franca Nova; but I am very biased to my Esperanto.

Answer (score 1):

There are languages created by groups, but they aren't international and they're more like dialects of existing languages. For example, Mandarin, New Norwegian, and Modern Hebrew; these are all successful constructed languages (or dialects) but I doubt they were made by a single person. You can also argue that languages like French or Icelandic, which almost always create all new words instead of taking loanwords for new ideas and things, are artificial (this is done by groups and organizations too).

But for a world-wide language project, the people who want to create a good international language have no money, therefore no support, advertising, clout, etc. The existing organizations, like the UN, which by all means should create their own language or use some kind of bridge language like Esperanto, don't want to do so because it means "change" (they're scared of changing stuff and then failing even more than they are now, on the language issue). For example, ANY language no matter if constructed or not, would get big if it sent abroad as many movies as the USA does; likewise, anyone would try learning a language if they were given a fistful of cash in order to do so (meaning, learn it and we'll pay you extra to act in a movie for it).

However the people who do have this kind of money don't care one bit, for example, many rich Americans donate extremely little money to charity compared to, for example, rich Swedes - and creating or sponsoring an international language is just like a form of charity. Otherwise, organizations actually look for solutions in the wrong area without even considering the constructed language idea, ex. simply telling everyone to learn whatever is the biggest language at the time (French, Latin, English, Chinese), simply spending more money on translators, simply trying to have kids learn 3 foreign languages in school, etc.

The last aspect is English itself, basically English-speakers are much less likely to learn other languages and they're much more likely to force their language on others (McDonald's advertises in English here in Sweden, for example). This is true whether it's the UK or the US, but the problem is that those countries are where a LOT of money is, a lot of organizations, and so on - and they live in such an English-speaking bubble that they don't actually realize how much of a language problem exists for the rest of the world. The basic idea that most countries nowadays have is, if the English-speaking population doesn't like something, it's not going to get enough money or support for it to become a world-wide success (which isn't true at all, but it's the psychology that matters).

Answer (score 1):

While this may not be an answer to your question exactly your question is one I've asked myself before.  But this is what I settled on.

The curious and beautiful anomaly of Hangul.  Korean didn't have a unified writing system at first.  But in the 13th century a writing system was devised.  The beauty of it is that the symbols themselves show how to pronounce the sounds.  Even the stacking system follows the same pattern if I recall correctly.  Someone correct me if I'm wrong.  To me this seems to be a beautiful blend of art and science.

I think there have been bits of this repeated.  Klingon and Vulcan were created in a collective way.  Vulcan has an especially [beautiful calligraphy](http://korsaya.org/vulcan-calligraphy/).  But a lot of the sounds are reported to be the creation of James Doohan by his mere observation of the actors speaking their parts in English.  It was only later "beefed up" by the linguist Marc Okrand.

Personally I feel the terms Constructed Languages/Artificial Languages are a misnomer.  All languages were developed at some point. We might have more "universal" sounds for some biological functions otherwise.

I never found an answer myself but rather chose to just accept that all language is art and virus. :)